# Security Onion (Ubuntu 16.04) syslog-ng to multiple sources

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, syslog-ng, bro

I'm setting up Security Onion to play with Bro, but I want to send the logs to an additional SIEM in addition to ELK (which is installed on Security Onion by default). The wiki [sends you here](https://github.com/Security-Onion-Solutions/security-onion/wiki/Syslog), which [redirects you here](https://github.com/Security-Onion-Solutions/security-onion/wiki/ThirdPartyIntegration). That page just says that if I want to add a destination, I add it to /etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf. So I did:

```
destination d_elsa { program("sh /opt/elsa/contrib/securityonion/contrib/securityonion-elsa-syslog-ng.sh" template(t_db_parsed)); };
destination d_logstash { tcp("127.0.0.1" port(6050) template("$(format-json --scope selected_macros --scope nv_pairs --exclude DATE --key ISODATE)\n")); };
destination remote { udp("192.168.1.55" port(514)); };
```

The top two lines are put there by the standard Security Onion installation, and my additional line is the third line. But that does not work. I tried using a name other than just "remote". I tried tcp and udp. Not only is my other SIEM not seeing it, I even tried tcpdump and that's coming up empty. I've searched everywhere and I don't see any other options. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the new destination in a log statement.

syslog-ng has three basic objects: sources (that receive messages), destinations (that send/store messages somewhere), and log statements that connect the sources to the destinations